# Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: solidity, blockchain, smart-contract

I am new to solidity . I am trying to build some smart contracts following a course . I have my "compile.js" file .When I run it using the command "node compile.js ",then it shows the error

> > "Range error :Maximum call stack size exceeded" .

But when I run the command

> > "node --stack-size=2000 compile.js"

then I get the bytecode and abi of my contract .I need bytecode generated from compile.js file to another file, until I fix this error it seems not to work.

I saw my node version has the stack size =984 . Is there any solution so that I can fix my stack size to 2000 or is there any node js version which has already 2000 default stack size or can I put any code in my contract so that stack size remain 2000 .

I tried many solutions

> > const v8 = require('v8');
> > v8.setFlagsFromString('--stack-size=2000');

I put this in my compile.js file .but it seems not to work .Thanks a lot .

here is my compile.js file

```
const path= require('path');
const fs= require('fs');

const solc=require('solc');

const v8 = require('v8');
v8.setFlagsFromString('--stack-size=2000');

const inboxPath=path.resolve(__dirname,'contracts','Inbox.sol');

const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath,'utf-8');

module.exports = solc.compile(source,1).contracts[':Inbox'];
```

here is my main smart contract

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.25;

contract Inbox {
    string public message;

    constructor(string memory intialmsg) public{
        message = intialmsg;
    }

    function setmessage(string memory newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

I checked my solc version and solidity version and both seems same :
here is package.json file

```
{
  "name": "inbox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ganache-cli": "^6.12.2",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "openzeppelin-solidity": "^4.6.0",
    "solc": "^0.4.25",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.26"
  }
}
```

I have been struggling with this problem for so long ,dont want to quit  here .Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, to reinstall the node modules. The contract is not so big to cause problems while compiling.

```
rm -rf node_modules && rm package-lock.json
npm cache clean --force
npm install
```

Also check with the versions of ganache and web3.js . The version of web3 you're currently using seems to be in beta.